# AMP Script not working when landing page move into content blocks

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I have written logic to insert data into DE on landing page(thank you page) in AMP Script and this page is called using post method from another page where user input values.
Everything worked fine but now my thank you page is modified and we have inserted different html blocks using gears and i have inserted my AMP script into  one of the html block but now values are not inserted into DE
My AMP script is simple i just used requestparameter to read the values
Any ideas will really be helpful

Comment: It's hard to help without any of your code.  Can you revise your question and include it?

Comment: @Adam Spriggs   Let me refresh my question : I have new welcome page which includes images for header, a block for videos, and footer which is created in design view. Initially it was only one page which i was created in Code view with AMP script and just simple message "Thanks for your feedback". Now I want to include the script into my new design page which i have mentioned in this comment at start. So where should i include this?? in which block?? or should we create new html block for AMP Script